# TypeError: f3() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x

This is the question from my exam, I cannot figure out why it ends with TypeError.

```py
    def f1(a,b,f):
        return f(a,b, f)

    def f2(a,b, f):
        return f(a,b,f3)

    def f3(a,b):
        return f3(a,b)

    f1(1,2,f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Crazy exam problem.

Best is just to work it out, calling the function and replacing the parameters in the result as you go:

```
f1(1, 2, f2) =
f2(1, 2, f2) =
f2(1, 2, f3) =
f3(1, 2, f3)
```

which is an attempt to call `f3` with three arguments, but the definition of `f3` says it only takes two parameters.

Good news is that the error message was correct, even though the call was made through a parameter, so yes it can be confusing.